# Vue Dev Tools - does not working "Open in Editor" button. How to fix this?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3, vue-devtools

I am trying to setup this feature from tutorial:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/master/docs/open-in-editor.md

but got an error

```
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft" не является внутренней или внешней, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Could not open LeadsEdit.vue in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: (code 1).

To specify an editor, sepcify the EDITOR env variable or add "editor" field to your Vue project config.
```

in my vue.config.js (project based on vue cli 3.0)

```
const openInEditor = require('launch-editor-middleware');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
    },
    devServer: {
        before(app) {
            app.use('/__open-in-editor', openInEditor('code'))
        }
    }
}
```

UPD. Without this code the problem still remain. 
UPD2.

I am trying to set EDITOR variable in .env file

```
VUE_APP_EDITOR=/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe
```

Or with vue.config.js

```
const openInEditor = require('launch-editor-middleware');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
    },
    devServer: {
        before(app) {
            app.use('/__open-in-editor', openInEditor('/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'))
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem still remains

What may cause this problem?
How can I fix this error?

Comment: If you're using a Vue-CLI generated project, "Open In Editor" should already work out of the box (without any configuration). I'm using vue-devtools `5.0.0 beta 3`, VS Code `1.28.0`, Chrome 69, and macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like dev tools is trying to open the editor executable `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft`, which is most likely wrong. The default install location on Windows 10 is (to the best of my knowledge) `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`.

`launch-editor` tries to find the editor from the currently running processes and falls back to the environment variables `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` (see https://github.com/yyx990803/launch-editor#why), so you can probably set the `EDITOR` env var to the correct path.

Probably, there are quotes missing around the editor config so it gets cut off at the first space. I don't really know where the path comes from, either you configured it via environment variables or in your vue project config.

Based on the information in your updated question, you could try this:

1. I don't know where the variable name `VUE_APP_EDITOR` comes from, but I guess it should be `EDITOR`. Change it to `EDITOR` and see what happens
2. The path you are using looks wrong (i.e. not like a windows path). Try `c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe` instead.
   E.g.:

   ```
       app.use('/__open-in-editor', openInEditor('c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'))
   ```

You can test whether the path is correct by starting a `cmd` shell and entering the path. If it is correct, VS Code should open. If not, it will tell you the path was not found.

Also have a look at this, there is some more on how to integrate vue devtools & VS Code: https://gist.github.com/moreta/d3989686b6a1f2416b5802cac8df16b4

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I am trying to set EDITOR variable in .env file or with vue.config.js


But the problem still remains